# Sum table column with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a table of All Sales, with the Client's Name, the date and the Sale Price.

I have a script for allowing a User to search through the table, but I would also like a script that returns a total for all the Sale Prices visible in the table.

e.g. If a User searches for T.Toe, then the script returns the sum of all Sale Prices for T.Toe.

code:

```
<table class="well table table-condensed small" id="academy">
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">
    <input type="text" id="search_academy" placeholder="  quick search" autocomplete="off">
   </td>
   <td><input type='text' style="width: 30px;" id='sum'></td>
  </tr>
  {% for sale in academy|sort(attribute="sale_date", reverse=True) %}
   {% if sale.price > 0 %}
    <tr class="success">
     {% else %}
    <tr class="danger">
   {% endif %}
  <th>{{ sale.sale_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}</th>
  {% if sale.client %}
   <th>{{ sale.client }}</th>
  {% else %}
   <th>{{ sale.concept }}</th>
  {% endif %}
  <th>{{ sale.club }}</th>
  <th class="prices">{{ sale.price }}</th>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

JQuery for live search over the table and returning a sum of the searched cells:

EDIT:

Thanks to @pointy and @user4621032 the script currently is:

```
 <script>$("#search_academy").keyup(function () {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

  $("#academy").find("tr").each(function (index) {
   if (!index) return;
   var id = $(this).find("th").text().toLowerCase().trim();
   $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });

  var sum = 0;
  $('.prices').each(function () {
   sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
  });

  $('#sum').val(sum);
 });
 </script>
```

I changed the parseInt to parseFloat to keep 1 decimal place.

This does return a sum of the all cells in the column with the .prices class. However I am looking for the script to return the sum of only the .prices cells returned via the User search in #search_academy.

Thanks!

Comment: if "prices" is an ID you can't have more then one of them. Make it a class and use the dot selector instead?

Comment: thanks @PaulCollingwood, i have changed back to class and the dot selector, (my bad on that code), but sum still returns 0.

Comment: why you not use Jquery Plugin  , like [DataTable](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: If the elements with class "price" aren't `<input>` elements, then they won't have a value accessible via `.val()`.

Comment: thanks @Pointy, how do I fix that?

Comment: Well if the price is the content of the element, then `.text()` instead of `.val()`, like in that first code sample you posted.

Comment: @Pointy Good one, thanks! That simple change does return the sum of all .price cells. However it returns the sum of the entire list (treating negative values as positive), while I am looking for the sum of only the cells returned by the User live search. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

replace

sum += parseInt(this.innerHTML);

ro

sum += parseInt($(this).text());

Comment: thanks @user4621032, but I can´t seem to make that work.

Comment: include the content of second keyup function into original search function

Comment: no, no error, but nothing is returned in the .sum cell.

Comment: check if summ is counted. add allert(sum);  after sum += parseInt($(this).text());

Comment: My mistake. For input field you need $('#sum').val(sum);